# Why "this" is null inside the React function invoked from HTML element

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React code as shown below:

```
export class TodoList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this)
  }

  addTask() {
    // why is this null 
    console.log(this.textInput)
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={(input) => {this.textInput = input}}  />
        <button onClick={this.addTask}>Add New Task</button>

        <h6>Pending Tasks</h6>
        <PendingTaskList />

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Inside the addTask function the value of "this" is always null. I know I can fix this by binding it but my question is why is it null in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's null because `this` no longer refers to the class. The best way to avoid this is to use arrow function.

From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this):

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has
>   its original meaning from the enclosing context.

```
addTask = () => {
    console.log(this.textInput)
}
```

Comment: But inside the function addTask "this" is null

Comment: It does not refer to the function, it's refers to the thing it was bound to. In this case it is unbound. You need to bind it to the instance in the constructor with `this.addTask = this.addTask.bind(this)`or use the [experimental public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) if you are using babel.

Comment: Why is it unbound? Usually HTML elements are bound to the window object  but is this onboard because this is virtual DOM.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Class methods are not bound by default.